# PHP - Get value of key in Json

Tags: php, json

I'm doing some tests using Behat, PHP and Guzzle to make HTTP requests. One of my request brought to me this Json response body:

```
   {  
       "products":[  
          {  
             "id":1466367,
             "sku":"PO870SHB32LET",
             "name":"T\u00eanis Polo Ralph Lauren Kids Day Bege",
             "brand_id":20901,
             "brand":"Polo Ralph Lauren Kids",
             "description":"test test test abc",
             "price":124.9,
             "original_price":179,
             "gender":[  
                "menino",
                "masculino"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

So, i made this function to get values:

```
    public function getJsonFieldValue($keyword)
    {
        $responseBody = $this->getResponse()->json();
        $jsonFieldValue = $this->recursiveFieldKeySearch($keyword,$responseBody);        
    }

    public function recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle,$haystack) {
            foreach($haystack as $key=>$value)
            {
                $current_key = $key;
                if(!is_array($value) && $needle===$key) {
                    return $value;
                }

                if (is_array($value)) {
                   return self::recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle,$value);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

If the value is "id" for example, the function can find and return the value. The problem is when i want obtain the values of "gender", my function always return FALSE for me. Someone can help me, please?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why do you "recursiveFieldKeySearch()"? Isn't the structure of the response fixed? Don't you know the structure? Such a generic function apparently helps but, in fact, it can make error detection more difficult. Write a function for each important value from `$responseBody` and everything becomes more clear.

Comment: There is no item with a key `gender` that does not have an array as its value, so you will never find it. And this is not the way to search your structure as you will find an arbitrary value when the keys are not unique. Like `0` in this case for example.

Comment: @DiegoUlrichZegaib just check at is_array if the needle is found to. Look at my answer.

Comment: @axiac My Json return always change, that is the problem. If the structure never changed, i'd  put the fixed keys. I'm not developer, i work with Quality Assurence, but i will propose to team a way to have fixed keys in Json return, but i don't know if my Product Owner will acept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you should change this lines of code. Basically if the needle is the array return it.

```
if (is_array($value)) {
    return self::recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle,$value);
}
```

to

```
if (is_array($value) && $needle === $key) {
    return $value;
} else if (is_array($value)) {
    return self::recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle,$value);
}
```

**Appendix by @trincot**

There are some values where your algorithm is not correct.

**Example**

```
{
    "products":[
        {  "a":1  },
        {  
           "id":1466367,
           ...etc.
        }
    ]
}
```

Here your algorithm wouldn't find id.

**Better Algorithm**

```
public function recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle, $haystack) {
    if (!is_array($haystack))      return false;
    if (isset($haystack[$needle])) return $haystack[$needle];

    foreach ($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $result = self::recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle, $value);
        if ($result !== false) return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thanks to @trincot for the Appendix

Comment: you are welcome, would be nice if you promote my answer then as an helpful answer and upvote it ;-) ...

Comment: This does not always find the value looked for.

Comment: @trincot The Question was why it is result in false instead of the array, not in write me the correct algorithm. I could rewrite his algorithm, too, relative easily. So you could just edit my answer and put it as appendix. Thanks!

Comment: @Kordi, I don't mind you took the example and code from my answer, but could you then at least mention this in your answer? I think that is the least you could do in such a case. Otherwise it looks like "stealing" from the effort I made.

Comment: @trincot sure thought it is clear from the comments. But i added a thank you and in the appendix heading. And I voted your comment, where you mentioned it.

Comment: OK, a vote on my answer would be more of value than on the comment, but I will not insist :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are more problems with the code. For instance, if you would have two sibling arrays, and the key is somewhere in the second, your code will not find it.

**Example:**

If in your JSON string you would add `{  "a":1  },` as the first element of *"products"*, like this:

```
{
    "products":[
        {  "a":1  },
        {  
           "id":1466367,
           ...etc.
        }
    ]
}
```

then with your code you will not find *"id"*. This is because the function will exit with `false` even before getting at the second array element of *"products"*.

**Solution**

Try this instead:

```
public function recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle, $haystack) {
    if (!is_array($haystack))      return false;
    if (isset($haystack[$needle])) return $haystack[$needle];

    foreach ($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $result = self::recursiveFieldKeySearch($needle, $value);
        if ($result !== false) return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, worked. But you are right, if i have two identical keys, but with diferent values, the function will return the first one. In other words, my assert can fail, but is not a bug, because my code just ignore the others keys that have the same name.

Comment: You're welcome. I was probably not clear about what I found your code was missing besides what you mentioned in the question. So for completeness sake, I added an example in my answer, showing a case where your original code would not find a key, if it was present in an array, that itself is the second array element of the parent. You may want to use this as a test case for other answers.